# FusedLocationProvider sending pendingIntents nonstop

Tags: android, location, android-pendingintent, fusedlocationproviderapi

Android Device Monitor:

[image: Non stop intents]

My Location Update Service is receiving thousands of intents per second. I'm not sure what's triggering it

Instantiation and calling Fused Location, I implemented `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` so I can start the location request when I receive `onConnected`

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private boolean mInProgress = false;
private static int INTERVAL = 10*60*1000;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(20)
            .setFastestInterval(INTERVAL)
            .setInterval(INTERVAL);

    intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdateService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    Log.d(TAG, "on create");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to FusedLocationAPI");
    mInProgress = false;
    Log.d(TAG, "Fastest interval : " + mLocationRequest.getFastestInterval());
    Log.d(TAG, "interval : " + mLocationRequest.getInterval());

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, pendingIntent);

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
}
```

My Update Service that receives the Location is straightforward, it will call another service to do something with the location data

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

        sIntent = new Intent(this, DoWork.class);

        sIntent.putExtra("LATITUDE", location.getLatitude());
        sIntent.putExtra("LONGITUDE", location.getLongitude());

        startService(intent);

        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand has Intent : " + startId);
        stopSelf(startId);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand no Intent");
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If I comment out the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` line, the intents are not fired as expected, so it leads me to believe the request is constructed badly or I'm not handling the intent properly to signal that I've processed it, I can't find anything related to either of these

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) for    `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` or   `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` ?
Also i made it with intentService and override in onHandleIntent

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("locationtesting", "accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy() + " lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " lon: " + location.getLongitude());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would accuracy have anything to do with the report interval

Comment: when you set the Priority, you are also saying how to get the location( only wifi or wifi & Cell tower, so you could get more information more often) [google LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int))

Comment: My phone was completely charged when I was testing this earlier - I will try it out when I get the chance.

I don't think using an intentService would make a difference would it? The FusedLocationProvider should be agnostic to what receives the intent